# Can I use while and source in the bash script?

Tags: bash

I have this script, it's cut down, but fine for this example:

```
#!/bin/bash

source /home/user/configs/config-file

while read host; do

find /home/user/configs/$host.cfg -type f -exec sed -i 's/value=./#value= /g' {} \;

echo "value="$value >> /home/user/configs/$host.cfg

done < hosts.list
```

The hosts.list file contains a list of hostnames

```
XYZ123
ABC567
LIN999
```

etc. The config-file contains entires like:

```
value=ZZZZZZZ
othervalue=YYYYYYY
3rdvalue=XXXXXXX
```

Full script makes use of all values, this example just uses value
Hope that make sense.

Running this script creates a file with each hostname from the hosts.list file, but with a ? at the end, so one would look like XYZ123?.cfg
During the run process I see:

```
find: â/home/user/configs/XYZ123\r.cfgâ: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Short answer: Yes, you can use while and source in a bash script. Something else is wrong.

Comment: Your script might have DOS-style line endings. Try `dos2unix script.sh`

Comment: Also, your sed looks wrong. You are searching for the regex `value=.` and replacing with `#value- ` -- you are relplacing the first char after the equal sign with a space. You are also replacing `othervalue=YYYY` with `other#value= YYY`. You want `sed -i 's/^value=/#&/'`

Comment: Thanks for all your comments.
I have some further info.
I see it's not about source and while.

The issue seems to be my hosts.list file.
It's created using php fwrite
When I use this file in my script, I get â/ and \r surrounding the path and filename but not including the .cfg
When I create the hosts.list file using nano, I don't get the error.
I have looked at the difference in these files, and I see none.  Both are ASCII, neither have any characters that should not be there (from what I ses).  I believe it's a PHP issue.

Comment: Fixed!  dos2unix converted the file and removed hidden characters ^M